# c++ - passing value between classes

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have 2 classes, `Qtree` and `Qnode`:

```
//QuadTree.hpp:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class QNode;

class QTree{
public:
    int depth;
    sf::Vector2f bound;

    QTree();

    void setRoot(QNode q);
};

class QNode{
public:
    bool isLeaf = false;
    int layer = 0;
    sf::Vector2f position;
    sf::Vector2f bound;
};
```

and

```
//Quadtree.cpp:
#include "QuadTree.hpp"

QTree::QTree(){
    bound = sf::Vector2f(100,200);
}

void QTree::setRoot(QNode q){
    q.bound = bound;
}
```

then in `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "QuadTree.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    QTree qt;
    QNode q;

    qt.setRoot(q);

    cout << q.bound.x <<endl;

}
```

and the `cout` result is `0`. I am expecting it to be `100`.
I am c++ beginner and did read a lot related to this from `google`. However still not sure how to get this to work.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `setRoot()` so it gets the argument by reference.

```
void QTree::setRoot(QNode &q){
    q.bound = bound;
}
```

Your code is passing by value, so `setRoot()` modifies a copy of `q`.

Comment: Based on your comment i tried `serRoot(QNode* q)` and in `main()`, I do `qt.setRoot(&q);`, and it works. and your suggestions works too. Is there a different between the one I do and your suggestion?

Comment: They're essentially the same. Passing by reference is more convenient because you only have to write it in one place, you don't have to remember to use `&` in all the places where you call the function.

Comment: Using a pointer is the C way to do it, C++ makes it simpler with references.